# Secure App with Api server with static jwt token

Tags: api, express, single-page-application

This may have been asked but maybe 2018 there is a better way. I"m trying to secure my api server and only grant access to my client apps I have created. Mobile / Web client apps that is using vue.js  for client app and express.js on node for api server.

Would is be wise to create a static token code it in on the client app. It would be sent with every api call. Then on the api server have my secret to the token. Verify the token before api call can be sent back.

Is there a better way? It seems to work fine but maybe there is something I don't know. Maybe everyonce and a while replace the static token and secret? The network would be https for sure. I am sending the token with every api call req.body.clientAppToken

What do you think? Thanks everybody!

Update this is express api middleware below.

App sends a manually created token to the api server on every request. Token is the same for all apps. I verify the token with the secret stored on the server. If it passes they get the data if it does not they do not.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('../config/config')

module.exports = {
  authClientAppToken (req, res, next) {
    // start see if client app jwt is correct
    /* eslint-disable */
    console.log('req.body.clientAppToken', req.body.clientAppToken)
    try {
        let decoded = jwt.verify(req.body.clientAppToken, config.jwtAppSecret)
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({
            error: 'We got problems'
        })
    }
    /* eslint-enable */
    // end see if client app jwt is correct
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I"m trying to secure my api server and only grant access to my client apps I have created. Mobile / Web client apps that is using vue.js for client app and express.js on node for api server.

The cruel truth here is that you cannot truly secure a web app because any kind of secret, be it a JWT token, a signed JWT token, an API Key or anything else you may want to use is very easily retrievable on the client side just by using the browser developer tools, aka F12.

On a mobile app developers may think that once they ship a binary that they can hide a secret there and keep it safe, well mobile apps are not as trivial to look into as using F12 in the browser, but they are easy enough to reverse engineer with tools like the [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF), that will extract all the code in the binary, thus exposing all the secrets stored on it. But even if the secrets are computed at runtime this tool is capable of doing runtime introspection on what your mobile app is doing, thus able to extract also dynamic computed secrets.

> Would is be wise to create a static token code it in on the client app. It would be sent with every api call. Then on the api server have my secret to the token. Verify the token before api call can be sent back.

So as said previously any secret generated or stored in the client side can be extracted and reused outside of the scope it intended to. Despite this I still encourage the use of them as 1 more layer of defence.

> It seems to work fine but maybe there is something I don't know.

I would recommend you to go through [this series of articles](http://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) on Mobile Api Security techniques to understand how https, certificate pinning, api keys, tokens, HMAC can be used to secure the API server and how they can be bypassed. While the article is in the context of a mobile api, almost everything applies in the context of an API serving a web app.

> Maybe everyonce and a while replace the static token and secret?

Using short lived expiration times on tokens is wise and recommend, but they just make the window where they can be malicious reused shorter but they will not prevent API abuse.

> The network would be https for sure.

While https should be always used by itself only guarantees that the data in transit is encrypted and cannot be readded by third parties, thus protecting the secrets in transit but will not prevent them to be reverse engineered from the app itself.

> Is there a better way?

For web apps you can make it hard by using a [javascript obfuscation tool](https://obfuscator.io/), implement [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) and if you want to go more advanced a User Behaviour Analytics Software solution on your API server.

Regarding mobile apps is possible to build them in a way that is not needed to store secrets in them in order to pass down in each call to the API server. The technique is called Mobile App Attestation and consists of a mobile sdk and a cloud service that work together to ensure that the mobile app is the same one uploaded to Google Play or to the App Store. The mobile sdk runs in the background and communicates with the cloud service that will issue a valid JWT token when the app is the original one and is not running in a jailbroken or rooted device or being object of a man in the middle attack. A valid JWT token is one that is signed by a secret only known by the cloud service and the API server, the mobile app does not know it at any moment, thus is not possible to reverse engineer or fake it. An invalid JWT token only differs from a valid one by being signed with a secret not known by the API server, thus making it indistinguishable from a valid one. This type of security solution can be found at [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html) and this is where I currently work.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will give it all a good read! But in regards to having the secret on the client. It wouldn't be.. It would be just a token and only the api server would know the secret to verify the token. Which would then approve the api request. I'm assuming someone would have to brute force the token to get its secret. Which I thought maybe you could get around by using a super long strong secret and replacing the token and changing the secret everyonce and a while. I"m sure i"ll find the answer in the info you  provided.

Comment: A token signed or not is considered a secret when used for identifications purposes. In your case you want to create a signed JWT token to store statically in the app for use in each API call?

Comment: Yes I have a token stored statically on the app. I created it manually. It gets verified on the api server before every request. If it does not get veriified the call to the server throws a error

Comment: This way I know the api request is from my app and not some random bot

Comment: Unfortunately as explain in the link I shared about API security techniques, any static secrets used to identify an app to an API server are easy to bypass by any attacker, including bots. The attacker only needs to reverse engineer the app to extract the static secret and reuse it afterwards in all API calls performed by the bot. Reverse engineer an app to extract secrets is very easy with tools like the Mobile Security Framework for mobile apps or just F12 for web apps.